Zip 2 lists with an offset, but keep left and right leftover
I have two lists that I would like to zip with an offset similar to here: Join two offset lists ("offset zip"?)
However I would like to keep the left and right leftover too, so the final result = left + zipped middle + right. I have the indices of a pair of values that need to line up in the middle.
Example
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
index1 = 2 # list1[index1] is 3
index2 = 1 # list2[index2] is "b"
# So 3 and "b" must be adjacent in the zipped_middle

# Result
left = [1]
zipped_middle = [2, "a", 3, "b", 4, "c"]
right = [5, 6]
final_list = left + zipped_middle + right

How can I achieve this in Python? It needs to handle lists of any size.

What have you tried? This is a very unusual problem (why are the indices the alignment point, rather than the start points?), and it doesn't exactly fit the description well (zip is a function in Python with specific behavior, your results are closer to round-robin-ing). Showing some effort, in the form of a [MCVE] of something you couldn't make work, is much more likely to get a response than "please do it for me" prompts. It might also be helpful to provide an example where the second list is longer, to make it clear what your intended behavior is in that situation.

This is basic logic and arithmetic:
offset = index1 - index2

# left
# reorder lists so left part always comes from l1
l1, l2 = (list1, list2) if offset > 0 else (list2, list1)
offset = abs(offset)
final_list = l1[:offset]

# middle
for z in zip(l1[offset:], l2):
    final_list.extend(z)

# right
# (at most one of these lines will add more elements) 
final_list.extend(l1[offset+len(l2):])
final_list.extend(l2[len(l1)-offset:]) 
# (note that len(l1) > offset otherwise the problem statement is nonsensical...)


list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
index1 = 2 # list1[index1] is 3
index2 = 1 # list2[index2] is "b"

sub = min(index1, index2)
index1 -= sub
index2 -= sub
left = list1[:index1] or list2[:index2]
zipped_middle = [x for xs in zip(list1[index1:], list2[index2:]) for x in xs]
add = len(zipped_middle) // 2
right = list1[index1+add:] or list2[index2+add:]
final_list = left + zipped_middle + right

print(left)
print(zipped_middle)
print(right)
print(final_list)

Attempt This Online!
